# Where to put SimpleSchema.RegEx.Url2 so it is usable in multiple simple schemas

Tags: meteor, meteor-autoform

New to Meteor.

I'd like to extend SimpleSchema.RegEx with an additional RE so that it is available in multiple schemas.  I've tried putting

```
SimpleSchema.RegEx.Url2 = /.../;
```

in lib, collections, client, and server but none seems to work.

Need some clues.

Thanks.

Comment: The logical place would be under `/lib/simple-schema.js`, can't see why it wouldn't work ?

Comment: Turns out this isn't actually a solution.  It works in some cases but not others.  When it fails starting the app with meteor yields: "Error: Invalid definition for picture field" on the reference to the RegEx.Url2.  I suspect the issue is dynamic load order but am unsure how to address it.

Comment: Issue turned out to be load order.  See solution below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my case I had my collections defined in

```
`app\lib\collections\simple_schema.js`
```

placing the RE in a file in that directory worked sometimes but not always.

The underlying problem was load order.  For collections in files with names that sort AFTER simple_schema.js, the additional RE was available.  For those with names that sort BEFORE simple_schema.js, the RE was not available.

Placing simple_schema.js in

```
`app\lib\collections\simple_schema_extensions\simple_schema.js`
```

resolves the issue as Meteor load order is depth first (well documented).